# Javascript multiple .innerHTML on click not firing

Tags: javascript

I Am dynamically loading data from my API. I have 3 buttons which I display only if the data is available.

Now for some reason, I am not able to add click event for each of these buttons no errors, no warnings nothing.

I have 3 buttons that are being added to the div container with innerHTML.

My Code:

```
/* global API_URL:true */

import Splide from '@splidejs/splide';

(() => {
    // Tijdlijn wrapper ID.
    const timeline = document.getElementById('timeline');

    // Als tijdlijn niet aanwezig is doe dan niks.
    if (!timeline) {
        return;
    }

    // Modal
    const timelineModal = document.querySelector('.timeline__modal');

    // Tijdlijn map & navigatie.
    const map = document.querySelector('[data-map]');
    const navigation = document.querySelector('[data-navigatie]');

    // Tijdlijn navigatie buttons
    let btnPrevYear = document.querySelector('.btn--slide-prev');
    let btnNextYear = document.querySelector('.btn--slide-next');

    // Splide navigation container
    const navContainer = document.querySelector('.splide__info');

    // Map & Navigatie opties
    const mapOptions = {
        lazyLoad: 'nearby',
        pagination: false,
        arrows: false,
        start: 1,
        perPage: 1,
        type: 'fade'
    };

    const navigationOptions = {
        isNavigation: false,
        pagination: false,
        arrows: false,
        drag: false,
        easing: 'cubic-bezier(.785, .135, .15, .86)',
        width: '35rem',
        start: 1,
        perPage: 1,
        type: 'fade'
    };

    // Gebiedsontwikkeling - map slider
    const YearMapSlider = new Splide(map, mapOptions);

    // Gebiedsontwikkeling - navigatie slider
    const YearNavSlider = new Splide(navigation, navigationOptions).mount();

    // Sync Map & Jaar slider.
    YearMapSlider.sync(YearNavSlider).mount();

    // Fetch API - Voor WP-JSON.
    const fetchWP = (value) => {
        let currentSlideIndex = value.index;

        const response = fetch(
            `${API_URL}/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=gebiedsontwikkeling-v2`
        );

        response
            .then((data) => data.json())
            .then((data) => {
                let current = data[0].acf.timeline_slide[currentSlideIndex];
                let hasPostSlides = current.add_post_slides;
                let hasSlideContent = current.slide_content;
                let legenda = current.map_legenda;

                console.log(hasSlideContent && current.slide_content);
                console.log(current);

                // handle Legend Map

                // Zijn er post slides aanwezig? Toon dan button "Ontdek".
                if (hasPostSlides) {
                    navContainer.innerHTML = `<button class="splide__btn--menu">Ontdek ${value.slide.innerText}</button>`;
                } else {
                    navContainer.innerHTML = '';
                }

                // Plan button is altijd aanwezig.
                navContainer.innerHTML +=
                    '<button data-button="plan" class="splide__btn--menu">Plan</button>';

                let btnLegenda = document.querySelector('[data-button="plan"]');

                if (btnLegenda) {
                    btnLegenda.addEventListener('click', () => {
                        console.log
                    });
                }

                btnLegenda.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    // e.preventDefault();
                    console.log('clicked');
                });

                // Is er een legenda map aanwezig? Toon dan button "i"
                if (legenda) {
                    navContainer.innerHTML +=
                        '<button data-button="legenda" class="splide__btn--menu splide__btn--info"><span></span></button>';

                    let btnLegenda = document.querySelector(
                        '[data-button="legenda"]'
                    );

                    btnLegenda.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                        let theContent = '';
                        let body = document.body;
                        e.preventDefault();
                        body.classList.add('toggle-legend', 'no-scroll');

                        theContent += `
                            <div class="modal">
                                <div class="modal__body">
                                    <a href="#" id="close"><span class="modal__close"></span></a>
                                    <h2 class="modal__title">Legenda  ${value.slide.innerText}</h2>
                                    <img src=${legenda} class="modal__image" alt="Legenda foto" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        `;

                        timelineModal.innerHTML = theContent;

                        if (body.classList.contains('toggle-legend')) {
                            document.querySelector(
                                '.modal__close'
                            ).onclick = function (e) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                body.classList.remove(
                                    'toggle-legend',
                                    'no-scroll'
                                );
                            };

                            document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
                                const key = e.key;
                                if (key === 'Escape') {
                                    body.classList.remove(
                                        'toggle-legend',
                                        'no-scroll'
                                    );
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });

                    console.log(btnLegenda);
                }
            });
    };

    // Events & Functions
    const onActiveSlide = (value) => {
        let currentIndex = value.index;

        // Compleet slider object doorgeven aan functie om vervolgens deze te kunnen gebruiken bij het ophalen van juiste data.
        fetchWP(value);

        // Zijn er vorige & volgende slides aanwezig?
        let hasPreviousYear = value.slide.previousElementSibling;
        let hasNextYear = value.slide.nextElementSibling;

        // Toon vorige & volgende jaartal in buttons.
        if (hasPreviousYear) {
            let previousYear = value.slide.previousElementSibling.textContent;
            btnPrevYear.innerText = previousYear;
        }

        if (hasNextYear) {
            let nextYear = value.slide.nextElementSibling.textContent;
            btnNextYear.innerText = nextYear;
        }

        // Als eerste & laatste slide item in array is bereikt toon dan geen jaartal in button.
        if (currentIndex === YearNavSlider.length - 1) {
            btnNextYear.disabled = true;
            btnNextYear.innerText = '';
        } else {
            btnNextYear.disabled = false;
        }

        if (currentIndex === 0) {
            btnPrevYear.disabled = true;
            btnPrevYear.innerText = '';
        } else {
            btnPrevYear.disabled = false;
        }
    };

    // Schakel buttons uit voor 500ms tijdens het laden van data.
    const disable = (selectorA, selectorB) => {
        const selectorClass = 'btn-disabled';

        // Timeout tijd vorige & volgende slide
        const timeout = 500;

        selectorA.classList.add(selectorClass);
        selectorB.classList.add(selectorClass);

        setTimeout(() => {
            selectorA.classList.remove(selectorClass);
            selectorB.classList.remove(selectorClass);
        }, timeout);
    };

    // Vorige & Volgende slide button event.
    if (!YearNavSlider.State.is(YearNavSlider.STATES.MOVING)) {
        btnPrevYear.addEventListener('click', () => {
            YearNavSlider.go('-1');

            disable(btnPrevYear, navContainer);
        });

        btnNextYear.addEventListener('click', () => {
            YearNavSlider.go('+1');

            disable(btnNextYear, navContainer);
        });
    }

    YearNavSlider.on('active', onActiveSlide.bind(this));
})();
```

What I am trying to is as you can see I have data-show: plan, Legenda, and discover.

For each of these data attribute values, I need a click event.

How can i do that?

Comment: Do you have any console errors?  Around the usage of the `btnLegenda` for making the event listener, in the case that you have the if check to make sure the element exists, your event handler isn't doing anything (`console.log` does not do anything).  And in the case of the event listener immediately after that if, if the element does not exist, that would be a null pointer exception.

Comment: Added console.log click but doesn't fire at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add the

```
onclick="function()"
```

Or actually dynamically generate and append the buttons with

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.setAttribute("data-show","discover");
//... Other attributes
button.className = "splide__btn--menu";
button.innerHTML  = "text inside button";
button.addEventListener("click", function (){
//Function code
});
navContainer.appendChild(button);
```